# How to increment counter of notification badge from adapter kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build an E-commerce app having basic functionalities. I want my number of items in the cart to reflect on the action bar. Currently, my UI looks like this.
[image: User Interface]

For creating the notifications this is what I have done:
**cart_layout.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cart_img"
        android:layout_width="30sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shopping"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_count"
        android:layout_width="18sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_height="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/itemcount" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My **cart_menu.xml** inside the menu directory looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/select_cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/cart_layout"
        android:title="Cart"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction ="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

My **onCreateOptionsMenu** functions inside Activity looks like this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu)
        val count:View = menu!!.findItem(R.id.select_cart).actionView
        val itemText:TextView = count.findViewById(R.id.item_count)
        if(cartList.size == 0){
            itemText.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        if(cartList.size > 0) {
            itemText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            itemText.text = cartList.size.toString()
        }
        return true
    }
```

Here **cartList** is the MutableList of items in the cart.

What I want to do is update the counter of this cart whenever the user clicks **"Add to cart"** button.
The click listener for this button is present inside Adapter class.
My **onclicklistener** inside **onBindViewHolder** inside **ProductAdapter.kt** looks like this:

```
holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener {
            holder.count.number = 1.toString()
            Log.d("Product","Clicked ${product.name}, count = ${holder.count.number}")
            val cartItemObj = CartItem(product.name,product.imageUrl, product.size, product.price, holder.count.number)
            val db = CartDatabase(context)
            val result = db.insertData(cartItemObj)
            if(result == (-1).toLong()){
                Log.d("ProductAdapter","Error in Inserting values")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            holder.addToCart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            holder.count.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            cartList.add(cartItemObj)

            // SOME CODE HERE TO UPDATE THE NUMBER OF ITEMS IN CART


        }
```

I don't understand how should I achieve this since I am unable to access the Textview inside the Adapter.
The link to the complete project is:
[Here](https://github.com/aniketbote/food-grain-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define cart count

```
 var cartCounter: Int? = 0
 //private lateinit var itemText: TextView
 lateinit var itemText: TextView
```

Then Update it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cart_menu, menu)
        val count:View = menu!!.findItem(R.id.select_cart).actionView
        itemText:TextView = count.findViewById(R.id.item_count)
        if(cartList.size == 0){
            itemText.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        if(cartList.size > 0) {
            cartCounter = cartList.size;
            itemText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            itemText.text = cartCounter.toString()
        }
        return true
    }
```

Finally when user click on add to cart update it again

```
holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener {
        holder.count.number = 1.toString()

        val cartItemObj = CartItem(product.name,product.imageUrl, product.size, product.price, holder.count.number)
        val db = CartDatabase(context)
        val result = db.insertData(cartItemObj)
        if(result == (-1).toLong()){
            Log.d("ProductAdapter","Error in Inserting values")
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        holder.addToCart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        holder.count.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        cartList.add(cartItemObj)
        cartCounter = cartCounter + 1;
        // or cartCounter = cartCounter + quantity_of_item;

        itemText.text = cartCounter.toString()


    }
```

Comment: "itemText" you used inside the onclicklistener is not accessible

Comment: @AniketBote I updated my answer, is because you define your `itemText:TextView` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` method. You need to initialise it before oncreat method

Comment: As I understand the val itemText: TextView should be initialized outside of the class. However to do that initialization is necessary.

Comment: If you initialise it outside `onCreateOptionsMenu` in a global scope, you can access it in `holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener`  or better still you can add `itemText:TextView = count.findViewById(R.id.item_count)` to onCreate method

Comment: In `val itemText: TextView;` Kotlin throws an error as "Property must be initialized".

Comment: @AniketBote you should use `private lateinit var itemText: TextView`

Comment: Remove the "private" label from itemText and I will accept. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to access the Textview inside the Adapter

Your adapter should not know anything about the menu and its items. But it can expose some observable field which can be monitored by an entity owning the menu - I guess it is either your `Fragment` or `Activity`. The easiest way to achieve this nowadays is by using `LiveData`. Create a new instance of it somewhere in your adapter:

```
class YourAdapter ... {
   val cartSize = MutableLiveData<Int>()
}
```

and update it from your click listener. Now you can observe this livedata from your fragment like this

```
override fun onViewCreated(...) {
   adapter.cartSize.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
       cartSize -> updateMenuCounter(cartSize)
   }
}
```

The last step here is to implement the `updateMenuCounter` which can access the previously created `MenuItem` and update its `TextView`.

Comment: As I understand instead of MutableList I should create a MutableLiveData and update this. However, I didn't understand what to do next. Sorry but I am a complete beginner in Kotlin.

Comment: you can create a separate live data storing integer value just for the counter but yes, the proper solution would be to use `LiveData<List<YourItem>>`. Live data is just an observable data container and essentially it only has 3 methods: `post(value)`, `setValue` and `observe`. use post/set to update it and observe... to observe :)

Comment: I understood that part. But where should I make changes in my [IndexActivity.kt](https://github.com/aniketbote/food-grain-app/blob/master/FF/app/src/main/java/com/example/farmfresh/IndexActivity.kt) to add onViewCreated()

Comment: `Activity` has no `onViewCreated`, it is for fragments. For Activity you can use `onCreate`. Or you can start observing your live data right from `onCreateOptionsMenu` callback, you already have direct access to your counter `TextView`.